# Create a custom block in totara

Tags: moodle, totara

I want to create a block in Totara that would contain my custom content.
I did not find on interface where this can be done.
I want this in short time so if anyone could answer will be a great help

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totara is a distribution of Moodle, so you can use the development guides at http://docs.moodle.org/dev.

To create a block see https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks

and https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks_Advanced